# Simple code to get GPS coordinates in android marshmallow

Tags: java, android, location, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-gps

i am developing an android app that targets marshmallow. i did enough searching but could not get a simple code to get GPS coordinates. i wanted a code that could give me GPS coordinates over some intervals. like for eg. every 10 mins i need to check the coordinates if person is in a specific area for duration of 30 mins. so app will check coordinates for every 10 mins that 3 times. Please help. :(

Note: i know about the gpstracker.java example available but it doesn't works for marshmallow.
I want the GPS coordinates in form of longitude and latitude.
Help with link is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 steps to solve your problem : 
1) There should be something that triggers your code (Fetching GPS Coordinates code) every 10 minutes.
2) The actual code for fetching the GPS coordinates.

Solutions: 
1) There are 2 ways you can schedule your code to run every 10 minutes : Alarm Manager or Job Scheduler

Alarm Manager can be used in lower end devices while Job scheduler require minimum api 21 Lollipop. Check out this tutorials for doing so :

[Alarm Manager Tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-alarmmanager)

[Job Scheduler Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html)

2) Now comes the part of actually fetching the gps coordinates. You can check out this article for that [GPS Location programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)